# How to get the THD value from the THD block in simulink into matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using the demo Simulink model for the [THD Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/thd.html) : it opens using the command : **power_RMS_THD** in Matlab.

[image: Pic of the Model]

Now i want to get the THD value displayed into Matlab (in our case the 50%).

- Should i do that from the **Display** block or from the **THD** block
- How do i do that ?

Comment: All your options [are explained here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/exporting-simulation-data.html)

Comment: Hi @Daniel i posted a question in math.stackexchange, could you please check it ? I will be so thankful.

Comment: Here is the link :
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690430/how-to-define-the-curvature-of-a-function-in-simulink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two simple solutions:

- You add a box "To Workspace" in your Simulink model and connect it with the THD signal.  (Simulink Library Browser: Simulink > Sinks > To Workspace) After the simulation, the data is in the field 'Data' of the specified variable (default: simout). So just call "simout.Data" afterwards to obtain the data.
- Double click on the scope 2. In the scope dialog box click on the gear and in the scope paramters dialog box on 'History'. There is an option to save also the values in the workspace.

Best regards